# Leer Carpeta de una camara Reflex conectada por cable a Raspberry pi

Tags: linux, debian

ando un poco atascado intentando leer el sistema de archivos de mi reflex nikon d5300, Debian detecta como usb la camara, me dice hasta el modelo y todo, pero no puedo acceder a el (o no se como). La tarjeta de la camara es de 32Gb, tambien he probado con una de 200Gb pero nada.

Adjunto mensaje del sistema cuando conecto la camara y el fdisk.

```
pi@raspberrypi:/media/usb0 $ dmesg | tail
[28450.551149] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[28479.671217] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[28510.871328] Under-voltage detected! (0x00050005)
[28542.782766] usb 1-1.2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[28549.731275] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 10 using dwc_otg
[28549.863662] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0431, bcdDevice= 1.00
[28549.863679] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[28549.863688] usb 1-1.2: Product: NIKON DSC D5300
[28549.863698] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: NIKON
[28549.863707] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 2853623
```

```
Device         Boot  Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192   137215   129024   63M  e W95 FAT16 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      137216 62333951 62196736 29,7G  5 Extended
/dev/mmcblk0p5      139264   204797    65534   32M 83 Linux
/dev/mmcblk0p6      204800   729085   524286  256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p7      729088 62333951 61604864 29,4G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Ha usado gphoto2?  Es muy bueno para leer fotos de camaras (y controlarlas tamblien.)

Comment: Cuando ingresas tu camara ¿Qué te muestra `lsblk`?